# backbone.js fetch failing in iOS safari, works in chrome

Tags: backbone.js, mobile-safari

I've got a bit of a strange issue with iOS safari and backbone.js.

I am trying to fetch a collection via a post command, my backbone code is

```
 MyApp.search_results.fetch({data: data,type: 'POST', 
                         success: function(response){
                                 //I do a bunch of stuff with success
                          },
                         error: function(){
                           alert('problem getting search');
                          }
                });
```

when I run the above code in chrome (both desktop and in iPhone or Android) I get the result no problem.

But using safari on iOS, I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

The big problem is my rails console does not even show that safari is sending the request, I see nothing past the previous request, so I'm getting a 404 error, but that actually isn't the problem.

Any ideas?

------------------------ update -----------------------

the problem is somehow caused by the `type: 'POST'`. I have removed and am now submitting a get request, but I would prefer this being a post type. So any suggestions on how to fix that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone internally set's the request method to `GET` for the `fetch` function. Trying to override it can cause any number of inconsistencies and is not recommended.

If you're trying to fetch data, then why not update your server code to read the `GET` params instead of `POST` params (or both)?